# Ember simple auth add token as query parameter in custom authorizer

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

How I can do to make the authorizer add the token as a query parameter in my requests to the server?

For example I have a GET to:
http://domain/api/resource

And I want the authorizer add the token:
http://domain/api/resource?token=TOKEN_DATA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that (by using the authorizer), looking at the documentation and source-code of ember-simple-auth I think you can only set headers not change the url when the authorize method is called.

If you really need that I think you might to have to do a custom ajax call.

```
let content = {}; //Your content
let session = this.get('session');
const accessToken = session.get('session.authenticated.token');
Ember.$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(content),
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${url}/?token={accessToken}`,

})
```

Comment: Thanks, at the moment I'm doing that and never use the authorizer.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with that!